# Неопределённое поведение при присваивании

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Объясните неопределенное поведение в коде:

```
int i;
i = i = i;
```

Comment: У Вас не инициализирована переменная int i. В присвоении самому себе ничего страшного нет, тк в operator= этот кейс корректно обрабатывается

Answer (score 5):

Согласно [черновику](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.indet#2) Стандарта C++ автоматическая переменная не инициализированная явным образом имеет неопределенное значение (*indeterminate value*). Если неопределенное значение получается путем вычисления - это приводит к неопределенному поведению (undefined behavior):

> If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined ...

Есть исключения из правила, связанные с беззнаковым узким символьным типом (*unsigned narrow character type*), но это не наш случай, т.к. используется `int`.

То, что переменная присваивается сама себе никакого значения с точки зрения Стандарта не имеет, т.е. записи:

```
int i; int j = i;
```

и

```
int i; i = i;
```

в плане проявления UB эквивалентны.

Цепочное присваивание два раза особой роли здесь не играет.

Comment: @Frostah,  если не упираться в стандарт и посмотреть на вещи чисто утилитарно, то можно сказать, что в 1) значение `j` станет равным значению `i`, а в 2) значение `i` не изменится. Какое именно число было (и останется) в `i` -- практически предсказать невозможно.

Comment: @avp если в Стандарт не упираться, то во что же тогда упираться?

Comment: В свои знания и здравый смысл разработчика компилятора.

Comment: @Abyx [вроде как](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#8) это должно быть не важно для самоприсваивания.

Comment: @avp: В `i` может быть, например, trap representation. Ну и как обычно — программы не выполняются построчно. Если написано `i = i`, нет гарантии, что это превратится в код чтения `i` из памяти, и записи в ту же память. Оптимизатор имеет право увидеть UB и выкинуть всю ветку кода как недостижимую. (И делает это.)

Comment: @VladD, с выбрасыванием кода `i = i;` (при оптимизации, независимо от UB (напрмер gcc превращает main с таким кодом в 2 команды -- xorl eax,eax; ret)) полностью согласен, но результат-то остается прежним (i не меняется). А с `trap representation` -- даже не представляю, что это такое в контексте чтения переменной (не памяти по указателю), а переменной, которую компайлер (с линкером и загрузчиком вместе) где-то в доступной памяти разместили.

Comment: Кстати, достаточно написать `volatile i;`, как компилятор реально добавляет  загрузку в регистр и запись регистра в память.

Comment: @avp: Ну, UB есть UB. Компилятор имеет право выкинуть не только это присвоение, но и весь код после него. По поводу trap representation [вот](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003). Ну и с volatile это тоже наверняка зависит от конкретной версии компилятора и опций оптимизации. Я бы всё же ориентировался на стандарт.

Comment: @VladD, Itanium, редкая  штука. ЕМНИП в Эльбрусе тоже был режим с тегированной памятью

Comment: @Abyx: Вы правы в C++98/C++03 (хотя там - дефект). Но в С++11 все секвенсирование было переработано. Было введено дополнительное секвенсирование для операторов, возвращающих lvalue. Для всех таких операторов гарантируется последовательность: сначала вычисляется новое значение, потом оно заносится в переменную-получаетель, а только потом наружу передается новое значение переменной-получателя. После этих изменений стало: `i = i++;` - UB, `i = ++i;`  - все нормально, нет UB. А также `i = i = i;` - все нормально, нет UB. Поэтому проблема с UB только в неинициализированности переменной.

Comment: То, что `i = ++i;` - больше не UB в C++ до сих пор удивляет многих, но это так. Точно также `i = i = i;` - больше не UB.

Comment: @Abyx я так понимаю, что [вот](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1): `The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.`

Comment: @Abyx, посмотрите [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562562/in-c11-how-to-determine-what-is-sequenced-before-others) ответ и ссылку из него. Там всё есть.